# fetching data using query from a particular table and showing it in admin side of django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a `Django` project and I want to fetch data from particular table and show it in the admin side.

I am having a `Company` model which I have registered in admin using `admin.site.register(Company, Company_Admin)`. Now I want to just get all the companies after querying them from the table and just show the result in the admin site.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default=None,max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(default=None)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    published = models.BooleanField()
    createdOn = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    updatedOn = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.text

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ['name', 'url', 'description', 'published', 'createdOn', 'updatedOn']
    list_filter = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name']
    filter_horizontal = ('keywords', )

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Now I want to create an option in admin panel that will show me all the companies that are published, that is, do not even show the non-published companies.

Comment: add published to list_filter

Comment: i need to only show companies where published value is true

Comment: you need a custom filter then, read django docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs on [`ModelAdmin.list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), you can try adding the field name to that attribute. This should give you a new filter option in the right sidebar of the change view.

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    ...
    list_filter = ['name', 'published']
    ...
```

---

If, however, you want to hide all non-published instances completely from the admin (I don't know if that is the case, I don't fully understand you question), then you can modify the [`ModelAdmin.get_queryset()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(published=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add list_filter in CompanyAdmin on 'published':

```
list_filter = ['name','published']
```

So, You can find one pane at right side, in which you can just filter out as you want.
(I'm considering that you're not overriding default admin template.)